# How can I disable the little preview on Youtube (to save mobile data)?

Tags: mobile-data, youtube

I am running on mobile data on my Galaxy S7 Edge on Oreo, and was wondering if you can disable the little previews. They take a lot of data, and I only get 3GB of data before it slows down to 2G. The reason they take a lot of data is cause they play at highest quality, but I watch Youtube at 144p on mobile data to save. Does anyone know how to disable them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android: YouTube now shows video previews in the Home panel, which uses up data and is otherwise just annoying. Happily you can turn them off.

Just tap your profile picture at top-right, then tap Settings > Autoplay. Turn off the “Autoplay on Home” toggle, as shown above, and you’re done.

It makes sense that YouTube would add a feature like this, because it gives users a very clear idea of what the video in question is going to be, but at the same time I understands why users might find this annoying. Happily it’s easy enough to turn this off.

Thanks to my friend Nancy Messieh at MakeUseOf for pointing this out to me.

Comment: Thanks! I set it to Wifi only to save data. On a low data plan you gotta save.